# Unit testing Entity Framework 6 with IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am currently in the process of adding unit tests for the Entity Framework 6 operations in my ASP.NET Web API 2.0 application, using the following MSDN tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314431

The tutorial suggests creating an interface to use in place of the application's DbContext class. This interface is then used throughout the application, allowing the controllers to be tested using a 'mocked' test context.

Below is the suggested interface from the tutorial:

```
public interface IBloggingContext 
{ 
    DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; } 
    DbSet<Post> Posts { get; } 
    int SaveChanges(); 
}
```

As I am using SaveChangesAsync() instead, I have modified the interface to the one below:

```
public interface IApplicationDbContext : IDisposable
{
    DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; } 
    DbSet<Post> Posts { get; } 
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Unfortunately this tutorial assumes that the context has a base class of DbContext, when mine uses IdentityDbContext as its base class (see below). There seems to be no way of calling SaveChangesAsync() - which I am using in place of SaveChanges() - from my context, leaving it unable to implement the interface correctly.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        // No way to call DbContext.SaveChangesAsync() from here
    }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Below are copies of the classes which are currently in use:

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        // Cannot resolve base.SaveChangesAsync() from here
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**IApplicationDbContext**

```
public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
    DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Example Controller Constructor** (which uses the interface)

```
protected BaseEntityController(IApplicationDbContext context)
{
    db = context;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

It does appear that there could be an issue with the class hierarchy. Below is another (hopefully related) build error:

```
UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'IApplicationDbContext' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'
```

For reference, my ApplicationUser class has a base class of IdentityUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
```

**EDIT 3:**

As mentioned by Jon, the error posted in EDIT 2 is to be expected. Unfortunately, the error also occurred for the context itself (ApplicationDbContext) rather than solely for the interface (IApplicationDbContext).

The issue has now been resolved, but only by uninstalling and reinstalling the packages from the solution, restarting Visual Studio, and then rebuilding the project. I am still unsure of the exact cause of the issue.

I have marked Jon's answer as correct, as it would be under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identitydbcontext%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) `IdentityDbContext` inherits from DbContext., so if you need to call directly then `base.SaveChangesAsync` should work.

However, really you don't need to implement that method, since its already implemented by `DbContext` in the "real" context unless you're using an explicit interface implementation or adding more code (which you're not in the example). You do need to implement something in the TestDbContext since it won't be inheriting from DbContext.

If I implement `SaveChangesAsync` as you have like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return base.SaveChangesAsync();

        // No way to call DbContext.SaveChangesAsync() from here
    }
}
```

Then on build I get this warning:

> Warning   1   'SOWorking.ApplicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync()' hides inherited member 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.

The build has no warnings if I either omit the implementation of SaveChangesAsync entirely, or add override like this:

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    return base.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

However, unless you have anything else to do in `SaveChangesAsync` then this is pointless (and Resharper greys it out for you as such).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Unfortunately, 'return base.SaveChangesAsync();' causes the build to fail as .SaveChangesAsync() cannot be resolved.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Is that in your `ApplicationDbContext` or the `TestContext`?

Comment: The `ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: @AndrewSula in this case we'll need to see full listing of your `AppDbContext` and related items. Jon is bang on about the inheritance structure and `SaveChangesAsync` should come all the way from `DbContext` to `IdentityDbContext` and to `ApplicationDbContext`. If you don't get this, means somewhere there is an problem in your class structure.

Comment: Thanks @trailmax - I have edited my answer to include the related classes.

Comment: @AndrewSula that code of yours looks legit. Is it possible that your namespaces are screwed-up and you are getting incorrect `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`? See this gist https://gist.github.com/trailmax/fc507480b4f9137225db for namespaces I'm using. That compiles and runs no problem.

Comment: Thanks again @trailmax - the namespaces appear to be fine. I've updated the question with one of the other build errors which I believe may be related to an incorrect class hierarchy, although I am still unable to see what might be causing this.

Comment: What versions of entity framework and the identity library do you have?

Comment: The error in the second edit would be expected - 'DbContext' does not implement 'IApplicationDbContext': That's only implemented by `ApplicationDbContext`.

Comment: @AndrewSula that is very strange! I'd remove interface from the dbContext and try to make it work without the interface. Then see if adding the interface adds to the problem.

Comment: Thanks again Jon Egerton and @trailmax for all your help with this. I'm still unsure of exactly what caused this, however it seems to have resolved itself after uninstalling and reinstalling the relevant NuGet packages. I have marked this answer as correct as it would be under normal circumstances.